# How to connect to Server on Desktop from mobile app developed in J2ME via socket connection on a port?

Tags: android, sockets, jar, java-me, j2mepolish

I have developed a mobile app using J2ME which uses socket connection to connect to Server running on a laptop.

I have used Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 software to test the app. Communication between server and mobile app is working fine.

But when i installed on a mobile (Nokia C5-01) and tried to connect to server listening on port 5000 via Socket Connection from mobile then no connection is established.

I have connected Mobile to a wifi and laptop to the same wifi where Server is running. So will it able to detect via Wifi?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the host/ip address that the client uses to connect to the server?

Comment: I have used hostname of desktop where server is running.

Comment: What is the hostname? Localhost?

Comment: Not localhost. Hostname is the output of hostname command. and i have also tried with IP address in ipconfig command.

Comment: Then switch off the firewall.

Comment: Firewall has been turned off and Antivirus is also turnedoff. Wondering why it is not communicating.